# How do you do a git diff of a particular Tag/Branch and the n-th version before that?

Tags: git, diff

So, I know how to do a diff with the HEAD and the previous version to the HEAD:

```
git diff HEAD..HEAD~1
```

or just

```
git diff HEAD~1
```

And therefore you can do `HEAD~n` to get the n-th version.

But how can you do a diff between some tag/branch (that is not the HEAD) and the previous version before that? I know I can scroll down the log file and pick a hash to diff it with, but I don't want to bother scrolling every time, sometimes I just want to look at the last n change(s)...

Answer (score 1):

damn... the answer was really simple and was staring me in the face.

If I have a branch named test_branch then I can do the same trick as with HEAD, i.e.:

```
git diff test_branch..test_branch~1
```

or more generally

```
git diff test_branch..test_branch~<n>
```

This notation is generic for all tags/branches - I had thought (for some unknown reason) that it was specifically for HEAD only...... still learning!

Comment: Right. Note also that you don't need the two dots here, and in fact, `git diff` (but only `git diff`—all other Git commands treat two dots as meaningful!) essentially just tosses them out: you can just `git diff commit1 commit2` to see the difference between *any* pair of snapshots. They don't have to be related by branch names or anything.

Comment: @torek, thanks for that update :)  ... I guess any "snapshot" can also be any "snapshot~n"? - I have only tested HEAD and branch-names so far, I assume tags work, not tried hashes yet either!

Comment: Yes, you can add `^<number>` or `~<number>` suffixes after tag names and hash IDs. See [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for the complete story (there is a LOT of syntax, I was mainly commenting on the fact that `git diff` has special handling for `..`, and for `...` too for that matter, all other Git commands behave as in gitrevisions).